# Why my Vue.js transition (CSS animation) is not trigger?

Tags: css, vue.js, css-animations

I'm trying to do a Vue.js transition with CSS animation and it's look like I've a issue.
I already did something close in the past but I can't find why it doesn't work this time.

I would like that my image switch to the other one when I click on in. And come back to the first one when I click again.

It looks to work but the animation-duration is not working. I set it on '5s' or '10s' but the transition is always instant.

I put everyting in one component. I know that it begin to be a long Vue component but I promise I will refractor once I will resolve this issue.

If someone has a idea or can help me, I would be grateful to him.

Here is my code below (the interesting CSS is at the end of style tag),

Have a nice day,

Dimitri

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <img class="phone" src="../assets/logo_cn.png" alt="logo"/>
        <div class="hamburger" @click="switchMenu">
            <transition name="flipping" mode="out-in">
                <img v-if="!showMenu" src="../assets/icons/icons8-menu-50.png" alt="icon-menu"/>
                <img v-else src="../assets/icons/icons8-delete-50.png" alt="icon-delete"/>
            </transition>
        </div>
        <div class="menu" v-if="showMenu">
            <a>Home</a>
            <a>Services</a>
            <!--<img class="desktop" src="../assets/logo_cn.png" alt="logo"/>-->
            <a>Contact</a>
            <a>Equipements</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component
    export default class CnHeader extends Vue{
        private showMenu = false;

        switchMenu(){
            this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    nav{
        width: 100vw;
        padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
        padding-top: 0.5vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background: #C0C0C0 linear-gradient(315deg, #B0B0B0 0%, #e1dada 74%);
    }

    .menu{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 3vw;
        margin-top: 1vh;
    }

    img{
        height: 7vh;
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 2vw;
        /*clip-path: circle(100%);*/
    }

    a{
        color: rgba(26, 13, 203, 0.90);
        font-size: 2em;
        font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .hamburger {
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 2vw;
    }

    .flipping-leave-active {
        animation: closeOnHimself;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .flipping-enter-active {
        animation: openOnHimself;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @keyframes closeOnHimself {
        from{
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
        to{
            transform: rotateY(90deg);
        }
    }
    @keyframes openOnHimself {
        from{
            transform: rotateY(90deg);
        }
        to{
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        nav{
            flex-direction: row;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Nevermind I forgot that in a transition, 2 identicals name tags (here img) need a key attribute to be distinct.
Everything works better with this 2 lines:
`<img v-if="!showMenu" src="../assets/icons/icons8-menu-50.png" alt="icon-menu" key="imgMenu"/>
<img v-else src="../assets/icons/icons8-delete-50.png" alt="icon-delete" key="imgDelete"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I forgot that in a transition, 2 identicals name tags (here img) need a key attribute to be distinct.
Everything works better with this 2 lines:

`<img v-if="!showMenu" src="../assets/icons/icons8-menu-50.png" alt="icon-menu" key="imgMenu"/>
<img v-else src="../assets/icons/icons8-delete-50.png" alt="icon-delete" key="imgDelete"/>`